# FFmpeg : Camcorder not focusing consistently, how can I create a clear and steady video image using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

The video I shoot was on a tripod but not clear at all times, sometimes clear sometimes blur. How can I use ffmpeg to make the video clear and sharp and steady?

I've tried this command but was not successful.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf unsharp=luma_msize_x=9:luma_msize_y=9:luma_amount=3 output.mp4
```

The blurry parts are still not clear and sharp.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: It's only possible in the movies. If it's out of focus, it's out of focus - the information about the detail is just not there. You can try to improve stills a bit, but there's no way you can just apply a single filter to entire video, partially blurry, partially not, and make it good.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply.